# Need to change “Posted on” to “Last updated on” in zerif lite theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, posts

I am using the zerif lite theme on my website.

I only need to change the text which says "Posted on" to "Last updated on". I can change the date manually using the wordpress editor.

I found out it has something to do with the `content.php` and `content-single.php`. However I have no idea what to do. Both of them have this code.

```
    <div class="entry-meta">

    <?php zerif_posted_on(); ?>

</div><!-- .entry-meta -->
```

Changing text in the above code to "last_updated" breaks the website, so I reverted it.

In `template-tags.php` there is a code which looks like this

```
function zerif_posted_on() {

$time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';

if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) ) {

    $time_string .= '<time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';

}

$time_string = sprintf( $time_string,

    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),

    esc_html( get_the_date() ),

    esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),

    esc_html( get_the_modified_date() )

);

printf( __( '<span class="posted-on">Posted on %1$s</span><span class="byline"> by %2$s</span>', 'zerif-lite' ),

    sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark">%2$s</a>',

        esc_url( get_permalink() ),

        $time_string

    ),

    sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s">%2$s</a></span>',

        esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),

        esc_html( get_the_author() )

    )

);

}

endif;
```

Can I change the text to last updated on here? Do I need custom code or can I just find a file where I change the text to "Last Updated on"?

Edit: I did changed the text from `Posted on` to `Last updated on` in the `Template-tags.php` , nothing happened, it is still showing as Posted On.

Comment: `Can I change the text to last updated on here?` Did you try it before asking the question? If yes, what was the result?

Comment: I can see the text in your code. Just change it manually. I don't think is that hard. I don't see what problem you have here.

Comment: I did, nothing happened.

Comment: It is still showing as "Posted on"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved my own question. I needed to change this text "Posted on" to "last updated" in my parent theme. I copy pasted the template-tags.php in my child theme and tried to do it but it didn't changed the text.

From this,

```
printf( __( '<span class="posted-on">Posted on %1$s</span><span class="byline"> by %2$s</span>', 'zerif-lite' ),
```

To this,

```
printf( __( '<span class="posted-on">Last updated on %1$s</span><span class="byline"> by %2$s</span>', 'zerif-lite' ),
```